# Mutate a value-type associated value in-place

Tags: swift, enums, pass-by-reference, value-type

Is it possible in Swift to mutate an enum associated value, which is a value type? If yes, How?

```
struct S { 
    var a = 1 
}

enum E { 
    case s(S) 
}

var e = E.s(S())
// the goal is to make e hold s with a = 2
// overwriting e is not allowed

if case var .s(s) = e { 
   // s is a copy at this point
   // I want to mutate e in-place
   s.a = 2 
}
```

**NOTE:** it seems to be possible, at least for the `Optional` enum `s?.a = 2` mutates `Optional<S>`.

---

Use case:

I am writing a tiny wrapper around `Codable`, to easily map values between dictionaries and objects. I have a single `MappingContext`, which is either `encode` or `decode`. Given that `KeyedEncodingContainer` has a mutating function while encoding, and I would like the user of this wrapper to avoid reassigning the value, and just directly mutate the associated value.

I opened swift stdlib code, and the function doesn't even mutate the struct, yet is marked mutating. Not sure why, but I can have copies without issues now, but also reassigning is an acceptable solution, just wanted to make sure I am not missing anything obvious.

```
typealias EncodeContainer = KeyedEncodingContainer<JsonCodingKey>
typealias DecodeContainer = KeyedDecodingContainer<JsonCodingKey>


public enum CodingMode {
    case encode(EncodeContainer)
    case decode(DecodeContainer)
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need it to be "in place"? For a value type, doing a read-modify-write has the same semantics as an in-place operation. You could just assign `e = .s(s)` after you mutated your local copy, `s`.

Comment: In Swift, you might experiment with `UnsafeMutablePointer`  `moveAssign(from:count:)`. Still, you need the address of the value and need to construct a new value (or a subcomponent). Looking at the disassembled code, it seems, it's not worth the effort compared to just read-modify-write approach. If you try to solve something fancy, like having a pthread_mutex in an Enum which you need to initialise and destroy manually, this probably wants you to go back to C++ .  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change an enum associated value, without overwriting the enum itself; if instead `S` is declared as `class`, it's a quite trivial task.

Anyway I did some experiments that I report here:

1) based on [withUnsafeMutablePointer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2429788-withunsafemutablepointer):

```
var e = E.s(S(a: 1))
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &e, {
   $0.pointee = E.s(S(a: 2))
})
print(e)
```

---

2) declaring a mutating `func` for overwriting implicitly the enum

```
struct S {
   var a = 1
}

enum E {
   case s(S)
   mutating func setS(val:S) { self = E.s(val) }
}

var e = E.s(S(a: 1))
e.setS(val: S(a: 2))
print(2)
```

---

3) if `S` is a `class`:

```
class S:CustomDebugStringConvertible {
   var a = 1
   var debugDescription: String { return "\(a)" }
}

enum E {
   case s(S)
}

let e = E.s(S())
if case let .s(s) = e {
   s.a = 2
}
print(e)
```

Comment: This overwrites `e` with a new  `E` value, in the same way as `e = E.s(S(a: 2))` does.

Comment: Yes, it does. But I changed the value not the pointer. On my console:
`0x00007fbe355083c0`
`s(TestMutate.ViewController.S(a: 2))`
`0x00007fbe355083c0`

Comment: How do you get that address?

Comment: `print("\($0)")`

Comment: I can see no difference between `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &e, { $0.pointee = E.s(S(a: 2)) })` and `e = E.s(S(a: 2))`. Both create a new `E` value and assign it to `e`.

Comment: Well, It was a funny test, anyway I think the best way to change the enum might be: `mutating func setS(val:S) { self = E.s(val) }`, but it's an implicit overwriting.